# How can I enforce aliasing with Audacity?

Tags: audio, aliasing

I would like to hear how [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing) sounds like. How can I get this with Audacity?

(I was told that I should adjust the Fourier coefficients in Audacity. I have no idea where I can do so / how I should adjust them.)

Comment: I don't know how to do it in Audacity, but there's actually an audio sample in the wikipedia article.

Comment: I want to hear it on natural language.

Comment: A simple method would be to take a recording, throw away every other sample, and play it at half the sampling rate. Alternatively, set every other sample to zero, and play at the original sampling rate.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it in Audacity, it filters automatically

Comment: @endolith Do you know any other program that can do so (Python scripts are ok, too)

Comment: @endolith, toss (by setting it to zero) every odd-numbered sample, and double (if it doesn't cause saturation) the even-numbered samples.  don't filter, just play it.  if that doesn't do it, toss 3 of 4 samples and quadruple the one remaining.  if that doesn't do it, toss 7 of 8 samples and multiply the remaining sample by 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Python script that does what Matt L said:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""Enforce aliasing by reducing an audio-file to every n'th frame."""

from scipy.io.wavfile import read, write


def main(inputFilename, outputFilename, n):
    rate, data = read(inputFilename)
    write(outputFilename, rate/n, data[::n])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from argparse import ArgumentParser, ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter
    parser = ArgumentParser(description=__doc__,
                            formatter_class=ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument("-i", "--input", dest="inputfile",
                        help="input WAV file", metavar="FILE")
    parser.add_argument("-o", "--output", dest="outputfile",
                        help="output WAV file", metavar="FILE")
    parser.add_argument("-n",
                        dest="n", default=2, type=int,
                        help="every n'th frame gets played")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args.inputfile, args.outputfile, args.n)
```

It might not be audible at factor = 2.  Try other powers of 2.

Comment: Could the person who downvoted this answer please explain why?